# What is the function of "enfin" in this context?

Tags: sens

> Ils ont trouvé leurs corps après le feu... **enfin**, ce qu'il en restait.

I’m not sure what "enfin" means here, as it doesn’t seem to fit any of the several definitions of "enfin" that I’ve known so far.

In English, I’m tempted to interpret it as "or rather..." for giving a more precise description of a situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Enfin*** matches here the `II.-A.-2.-b)` definition of its [TLFI](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/enfin) entry:

> **II.−** [En tenant compte d'un **interlocuteur présent**; gén. avec un autre mot plus ou moins grammaticalisé]
>   **A.−** Valeur log. [Pour mettre fin à son propre discours ou l'**abréger** ou l'interrompre momentanément en présence d'autrui et par égard pour lui]
>   ...
>   **2.** [En appos. ou **en incise**, dans un énoncé, **pour introduire une information**]
>   ...
>   **b)** [**rectificative, restrictive**] Synon. du moins. *Enfin disons, enfin à mon sens. Autour de vous, vos camarades sont tous pareils? − Tous... **enfin**, tous ceux qui existent, qui réfléchissent* (Daniel-Rops, Mort, 1934, p. 468):

The TLFI suggests *du moins* (**at least**) but **rather** is indeed also a good translation here.

> They found their (dead) bodies after the fire... or (at least/rather) what was left of it.

Answer (score 3):

"Or rather" works, but I'd probably just say "well." It's sort of a minor correction, similar to how you might use it if you don't quite say what you meant to say, e.g., *Je dois travailler demain, enfin, je dois me rendre au bureau pour prendre des documents.*